# custom_entry_meta() not working in single_*.php, but does in search.php and category.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes

I've been researching online and been trying to use theme_entry_meta( bool, bool, etc... ) to display author, date, categories, tags, comments which are controlled by bool(s).

The question I have is that when I apply this within modified child theme search.php or a category.php page theme_entry_meta() function outputs the bools I designated as 'TRUE' and null for the ones designated as 'FALSE' as it should.

However, when I attempted to use the same function, with essentially the same CPT structure and layout within a single_*.php page, nothing is output...

Things I've tried, non exhaustive list:

1. adjusting the themes template-support.php theme_entry_meta() declaration to include, get_the_ID() as an argument, so that the ID may be manually passed through to the function, no output,
2. Changing my foreach() loop to an if, while conditional loop statement where the other instances of theme_entry_meta() works, no output,
3. Changing scope to:  Global $post (and $wp_query), so that the foreach() loop has access to the $post->ID, no output,
4. I've taken the variable declarations from the search.php and category.php (limited declarations in category.php) to try to troubleshoot or identify what could possibly be wrong,
5. I've also used setup_postdata( $post ) to ensure (meta)data is passed through to theme_entry_meta(),
6. I've checked error_log, var_dump(), and print() to see if it would provide any clues.  The clue I got was that the function (theme_entry_meta) is not receiving post->ID which is why it is returning 'NULL',
7. Checked S/O and relevant material online, without any thing I've noted already,
8. I've rewritten the function as a custom_entry_meta() function which declares all the meta data I am looking for, which does output metadata, however is missing icons and css styling already created for the actual theme_entry_meta() function, while also not being responsive when I turn "off" an argument.

Below is a code snippet of the custom_entry_meta() function that I tried and worked, if the actual foreach() loop is required I'll also post it if necessary.

```
function custom_entry_meta( $get_the_author = true | false, $get_the_category_list = true | false, $get_the_date = true | false, $get_the_tag_list = true | false, $get_comments_number = true | false ){
  echo $get_the_author = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), $size = '63' );
  echo $get_the_category_list = get_the_category_list(', ');
  echo $get_the_date = get_the_date();
  echo $get_the_tag_list = get_the_tag_list('', ', ');
  echo $get_comments_number = get_comments_number();
}
```

**Edit**
Thank you @hovercraft full of eels for instructing me to edit, wasn't exactly sure how to communicate my miscommunication.

For clarity function `custom_entry_meta( bool, bool, bool, bool, bool)` was my work around for the code described below, which does not work within single_*.php pages, but for some reason does within category.php and search.php.  I'd like to understand why and also limit the amount of 'duplication' of functions that essentially do the same thing.

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_entry_meta' ) ) :
    /**
    * Prints HTML with the comment count for the current post.
    */
    
    function theme_entry_meta( $theme_show_author = true, $theme_show_date = true, $theme_show_categories = true, $theme_show_tags = true, $theme_show_comments = true, $theme_human_diff = null, $theme_title_section = false ) {
    
    /**
    * Fires before entry meta.
    *
    * @since theme 0.5.1
    */
    do_action( 'theme_entry_meta_before', $theme_show_author, $theme_show_date, $theme_show_categories, $theme_show_tags, $theme_show_comments, $theme_human_diff, $theme_title_section );
    
    $show_comments_first = ( 'default-centered' !== theme_option( 'blog_layout' ) ) && ( ! is_singular() );
    
    //float right comments
    if ( ! empty( $theme_show_comments ) && ! empty( $show_comments_first ) ) :
    theme_comment_count( $theme_title_section );
    endif; //comments
    
    
    if ( ! empty( $theme_show_author ) ) :
    /**
    * Fires before entry meta author.
    *
    * @since theme 2.0.2
    */
    do_action( 'theme_entry_meta_before_author', $theme_title_section );
    theme_the_author( $theme_title_section );
    endif; //author
    
    
    if ( ! empty( $theme_show_date ) ) :
    /**
    * Fires before entry meta date.
    *
    * @since theme 2.0.2
    */
    do_action( 'theme_entry_meta_before_date', $theme_title_section );
    theme_the_date( $theme_human_diff, $theme_title_section );
    endif; //date
    
    
    if ( ! empty( $theme_show_categories ) ) :
    /**
    * Fires before entry meta categories.
    *
    * @since theme 2.0.2
    */
    do_action( 'theme_entry_meta_before_categories', $theme_title_section );
    theme_the_categories( $theme_title_section );
    endif; //categories
    
    
    if ( ! empty( $theme_show_tags ) ) :
    /**
    * Fires before entry meta tags.
    *
    * @since theme 2.0.2
    */
    do_action( 'theme_entry_meta_before_tags', $theme_title_section );
    theme_the_tags( $theme_title_section );
    /**
    * Fires after entry meta tags.
    *
    * @since theme 2.0.2
    */
    do_action( 'theme_entry_meta_after_tags', $theme_title_section );
    endif; //tags
    
    
    //centered comments in archive are last in order
    if ( ! empty( $theme_show_comments ) && empty( $show_comments_first ) ) :
    theme_comment_count( $theme_title_section );
    endif; //comments
    
    /**
    * Fires after entry meta.
    *
    * @since theme 0.5.1
    */
    do_action( 'theme_entry_meta_after', $theme_show_author, $theme_show_date, $theme_show_categories, $theme_show_tags, $theme_show_comments, $theme_human_diff, $theme_title_section );
    
    }
    endif;
```

Any guidance or direction on how to get this function to work within a single_*.php structure would be great, I surmise I may be missing something with the scope or declaration of variables somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the WordPress functions `get_the_...` don't work outside of the standard WordPress loop. The way the loop works is typically used on each `single_*.php` file should be the same as `search.php`.

```php
custom_entry_meta(); // May not work here.
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    custom_entry_meta(); // Should be working here.
endwhile;
```

The main part is the `the_post()` function, so I'll often add it above the `get_header()` call on `single_*.php` files.

Comment: @xii: please don't post code in comments as you are not able to format it so that it is readable, and more importantly, it's likely too important to be buried in comments. Instead, edit your original post and add any updates and code there.

Comment: Hi @HovercraftFullOfEels after the edit to original post, should I remove the code I placed in comments to accord with site best practices?